# display array conditionally : Angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I'm trying to filter my array : here is my fiddle : [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/z7sdh7dj/2/).
there are two select list , here is the condition :

```
when top select list === 123        ====> bottom select list should show 001,002,003
```

and

```
when top select list === 1234        ====> bottom select list should show 002,004,005
```

should i use something like this `.slice(1, 3)` ?
Many Thanks

Comment: How did you decide that 1234 should show 002,004,005. You should try and include the actual scenario you are trying to achieve, instead of making up a random scenario.

Comment: Can you explain the logic behid the critiera? Why should `1234` be `002, 004, 005`?

Comment: this is the rule , this is not a random or fake scenario , that's what our team should create

Comment: I don't know really , because product owner gives us this task and we don't ask about logic .

Comment: Here is a fiddle that does what you want, where 1234 shows 002,004,005 just because it does. [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gabs00/7htqdk7y/1/)

Comment: Hey @Gabs00 thx , saved my day , please put that in answer section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a fiddle that does what you want, where 1234 shows 002,004,005 just because it does. [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gabs00/7htqdk7y/1/)

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
$scope.colors = [
    {name:'black', shade:'123'},
    {name:'white', shade:'1234'},

];
var allRanges =  [
    {id:'001', number:'1'},
    {id:'002', number:'2'},
    {id:'003', number:'3'},
    {id:'004', number:'4'},
    {id:'005', number:'5'}
];

$scope.range = [];



$scope.check = function(){
    var filter;
    if($scope.color === "black"){
        filter = function(r){
            if(r.number < 4){
                return true;
            }
        };
    } else if($scope.color === 'white'){
        filter = function(r){
            if(['2','4','5'].indexOf(r.number) >= 0){
                return true;
            }
        };
    }
    $scope.range = allRanges.filter(filter);
}
```

});